# Angular 6 Get sorted data from Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Is there any way to get the sorted data from a material table after sorts on the table have been applied? I can see "filteredData" in the table datasource but there's no "sortedData". The reason why I want the sorted data is so that I can export it in a csv file while maintaining all of the sorts applied. I've been using the built in MatSort to sort individual columns in the table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a sort data method, that you can use with either datasource.data or datasource.filteredData

```
    dataSource.sortData(dataSource.filteredData,dataSource.sort);
```