# Get sorted mat-table data with pagination in Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, pagination, mat-table

I have a mat-table that uses sorting and pagination. I have a requirement where I need to get the sorted data everytime the data gets sorted. 
I have an example here: [Mat-table with pagination](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1jdrt-kgpfp7)

In component.ts I have the following line which gets the sorted data:

`this.dataSource.connect().subscribe(d => this.renderedData = d);` in `ngOnInit` but it only gets the selected number of rows in the mat-paginator. I'd like to get all the data. Is there a good way to get this?

The `renderedData` object is displayed at the top of the page.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this feature is available. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545489/angular-6-get-sorted-data-from-material-table) SOF question which may be of help, although I couldn't get it to work. Else, I think you may need to post this as a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah I did see that SOF question and I will make a feature request on Github. Thank-you.